# How to fire onUploadError in jquery.uploadify.js

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I have learned that jquery.uploadify.js is based on flash and it contains a swf file - uploadify.swf that I can't edit.
My question is that I set some conditions in php logic when I upload a file.but I don't know how to abort and fire onUploadError.It always fire onUploadSuccess.

Does anyone knows that?